# Indented organization tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, tree

I'm looking for some algorithm solution for building organization tree / graph which allow indented or offsetted one or more level.

I have have set of json data:

```
[{
   "id": 1,
   "level":1,
   "parent_id": 0,
   "name": "Board of Director"
}, {
   "id": 2,
   "level":2,
   "parent_id": 1,
   "name": "Finance Division"
}, {
   "id": 3,
   "level":3,
   "parent_id": 2,
   "name": "Finance Department"
}, {
   "id": 4,
   "level":3,
   "parent_id": 2,
   "name": "Sales Department"
}, {
   "id": 5,
   "level":3,
   "parent_id": 1,
   "name": "HR Division"
}]
```

**Brief explanation**:
_parent_id_ attribute to connect divisions with its parent by using line, while *level* attribute for classifying where division should located or indented, for example : Level 1 (Board of Director), level 2 (Finance Division) and level 3 (Finance Department, Sales Department, HR Division). Due to HR Division has _parent_id_=1 and *level*=3, then position in chart should be on line level with Finance Department and Sales Department.

Below is mockup organization tree and examples of Indented as **HR Division** shown.

```css
.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  position: relative
}
.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto
}
.tree li::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px
}
.tree li::after {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  top: 30px;
  width: 25px
}
.tree li div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-decoration: none
}
.tree li.parent > div {
  cursor: pointer
}
.tree > ul > li::before,
.tree > ul > li::after {
  border: 0
}
.tree li:last-child::before {
  height: 30px
}
.tree li.parent > div:hover,
.tree li.parent > div:hover + ul li div {
  background: #f3f3f4;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
  color: #000
}
li div.just-line {
  display: none;
}
div.just-line + ul > li::before {
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
div.just-line + ul > li::after {
  left: -40px;
  width: 45px;
}
.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li data-id="1">
      <div>Board of Director</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Finance Division</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>Finance Department</div>
              <li>
                <div>Sales Department</div>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="no-padding">
            <div class="just-line"></div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div>HR Division</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And the problem is ???

Comment: I looking for some algorithm solution that can convert above json data to printed organization graph

Comment: Am it's expected that you try at least do it yourself, SO isn't a code write service. An idea get Json data --- search for level 1, append to ul --- then serach for level 2 --- append to parents ..... and that way long

Comment: thank you @DaniP for your suggestion. I will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get you started, this is a two step solution which generates first a tree and the renders the DOM.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 1, "level": 1, "parent_id": 0, "name": "Board of Director" }, { "id": 2, "level": 2, "parent_id": 1, "name": "Finance Division" }, { "id": 3, "level": 3, "parent_id": 2, "name": "Finance Department" }, { "id": 4, "level": 3, "parent_id": 2, "name": "Sales Department" }, { "id": 5, "level": 3, "parent_id": 1, "name": "HR Division" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r, o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            if (a.parent_id === root) {
                r = a;
            } else {
                o[a.parent_id] = o[a.parent_id] || {};
                o[a.parent_id].children = o[a.parent_id].children || [];
                o[a.parent_id].children.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, 0),
    ul = document.createElement('ul');

[tree].forEach(function iter(level) {
    return function (a) {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            div = document.createElement('div'),
            ul,
            l = level;

        this.appendChild(li);
        while (++l < a.level) {
            div.className = 'just-line';
            li.className = 'no-padding';
            li.appendChild(div);
            ul = document.createElement('ul');
            li.appendChild(ul);
            li = document.createElement('li');
            ul.appendChild(li);
            div = document.createElement('div');
        }
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a.name));
        li.appendChild(div);

        if (a.children) {
            ul = document.createElement('ul');
            li.appendChild(ul);
            a.children.forEach(iter(a.level), ul);
        }
    };
}(0), ul);
document.getElementById('tree').appendChild(ul);
```

```css
.tree li { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 10px 5px 0 5px; position: relative; }
.tree li::before, .tree li::after { content: ''; left: -20px; position: absolute; right: auto; }
.tree li::before { border-left: 1px solid #999; bottom: 50px; height: 100%; top: 0; width: 1px; }
.tree li::after { border-top: 1px solid #999; top: 30px; width: 25px; }
.tree li div { border: 1px solid #999; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 24px; text-decoration: none; }
.tree li.parent > div { cursor: pointer; }
.tree > ul > li::before, .tree > ul > li::after { border: 0; }
.tree li:last-child::before { height: 30px; }
.tree li.parent > div:hover, .tree li.parent > div:hover + ul li div { background: #f3f3f4; border: 1px solid #94a0b4; color: #000; }
li div.just-line { display: none; }
div.just-line + ul > li::before { padding: 0; border-left: 0; }
div.just-line + ul > li::after { left: -40px; width: 45px; }
.no-padding { padding: 0 !important; }
```

```html
<div id="tree" class="tree"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your great idea, I'll try to improve from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For coding I would opt for a MVC framework like AngularJS

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/

The only thing you would need to do is create a datamodel that resembles the structure. Yours is flat, I would opt to have tree like data, it's much easier to fit into a MVC like framework ;)

```
[{"id": 1,"level":1,"parent_id": 0, "name": "Board of Director", childs: [{"id": 2, ..., childs: [{}]}}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seen as the DOM is already a tree, we can take advantage of this fact.

The below I think does what your after.

```js
var data = [{
   "id": 1,
   "level":1,
   "parent_id": 0,
   "name": "Board of Director"
}, {
   "id": 2,
   "level":2,
   "parent_id": 1,
   "name": "Finance Division"
}, {
   "id": 3,
   "level":3,
   "parent_id": 2,
   "name": "Finance Department"
}, {
   "id": 4,
   "level":3,
   "parent_id": 2,
   "name": "Sales Department"
}, {
   "id": 5,
   "level":3,
   "parent_id": 1,
   "name": "HR Division"
}];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var 
    qsa = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document),
    ce = document.createElement.bind(document);   
  var rootparent = qsa('.tree UL')[0]; 
  rootparent.innerHTML = '';
  data.forEach(function (e) {
    var parent = qsa('[data-id=\'' + e.parent_id+'\'] UL')[0] 
      || rootparent;
    var li = ce("LI");    
    var div = ce('DIV');
    var ul = ce('UL');
    li.appendChild(div);
    li.appendChild(ul);
    li.setAttribute('data-id', e.id);
    div.textContent = e.name;    
    parent.appendChild(li);
  });
});
```

```css
.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  position: relative
}
.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto
}
.tree li::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px
}
.tree li::after {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  top: 30px;
  width: 25px
}
.tree li div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-decoration: none
}
.tree li.parent > div {
  cursor: pointer
}
.tree > ul > li::before,
.tree > ul > li::after {
  border: 0
}
.tree li:last-child::before {
  height: 30px
}
.tree li.parent > div:hover,
.tree li.parent > div:hover + ul li div {
  background: #f3f3f4;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
  color: #000
}
li div.just-line {
  display: none;
}
div.just-line + ul > li::before {
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
div.just-line + ul > li::after {
  left: -40px;
  width: 45px;
}
.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your hr division is not as nested, as in the example.

Comment: @NinaScholz  I did notice that, but he hasn't really said what logic he is using to select, I personally would say use the ID..  Modifying this to add a no-padding & just-line class should be easy.

Comment: i think it relies on the level. it is 3 for it, as finance and sales dept.

Comment: @NinaScholz  , I'm still none the wiser :)  I'm not sure how he decided that 'HR Division' want indenting.  You see I think he want's it indenting based on mouse hover, but I might be wrong, it might be a selected id etc.  Were just missing a bit of information to finish this off.  I've read his description again & again, but I'm unable to work that bit out.  Unless your seeing something I'm not..

Comment: i compare the acual level with the level of the parent and if it is greater than one, i add sime dummy levels before with `<li class="no-padding"><div class="just-line"></div>`, like in the mockup.

Comment: @NinaScholz There is no information in his description to say anything about  level / parent-level, I can see he had level = 3, where I wouldn't expect to see level = 3, but that could have even been a typo.  You might be right though, but I think we really need the OP to pop in here and give some clarification.  btw. well spotted in seeing that level oddity, you must have eagle eyes.. :)

Comment: I'm apologize for late response. First I want to thank you to all of you for taking time to help me. As @NinaScholz said, the level attribute for classifying where division should located or indented, for example : level 1 (Board of Director), level 2 (Finance Division) and level 3 (Finance Department, Sales Department, HR Division). Due to **HR Division** has parent_id=1 and level=3, then position in chart should be on line level with Finance Department and Sales Department as shown in my mockup.